# Mounting /tmp in another drive on RHEL 7.2 in AWS

Tags: fstab

I'm running RHEL 7.2 in Amazon Web Services and am trying to make my `/tmp` use an attached 10 GB volume `/dev/xvdh`.  Data does not need to persist, but I have to have a bigger volume just for tmp, because of a customer requirement.  Here's the entry in my `fstab`.

```
/dev/xvdh       /tmp    xfs     defaults,nofail 0  2
```

When I run `sudo mount -a`, I don't get any errors, and yet, when I reboot, I don't see this mounting when I run `lsblk`, as seen below.

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  10G  0 disk
├─xvda1 202:1    0   1M  0 part
└─xvda2 202:2    0  10G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0   8G  0 disk /grid/01
xvdc    202:32   0   8G  0 disk /grid/02
xvdd    202:48   0   8G  0 disk /grid/03
xvde    202:64   0   8G  0 disk /grid/04
xvdf    202:80   0   8G  0 disk /grid/05
xvdg    202:96   0  20G  0 disk /var/log
xvdh    202:112  0  10G  0 disk
```

Got any pointers?  The drive definitely exists...

I was asked to add the output of `mount`, here it is:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=484472k,nr_inodes=121118,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/xvda2 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/xvdb on /grid/01 type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/xvde on /grid/04 type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/xvdd on /grid/03 type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/xvdg on /var/log type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/xvdf on /grid/05 type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/xvdc on /grid/02 type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=101548k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

here's the output of `df /tmp`:

```
/dev/xvda2      10473452 1603440   8870012  16% /
```

## Edit: Like Edison says...

Well, I found another way that won't work.  [Per this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1176170), I tried masking this file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount`, but my mapping for `/tmp` still wouldn't work on reboot. So then I tried renaming the file, also didn't work.  I restored the file and removed the mask.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l / | awk '/tmp/{print $1}'` after you manually mount `/tmp`?

Comment: `drwxrwxrwt` are the permissions when I run that command.

Comment: When you say "its not persistent", the fstab gets somehow modified or what?

Comment: fstab stays the same, but the disk never gets mounted as /tmp.

Comment: Please post the output of `mount` and `df /tmp`.

Comment: The `nofail`option suppresses error messages. Try removing it and rebooting and see if there are error messages while booting.

Comment: @Gilles, I added the output of those commands to my original post.  This is an AWS instance of RHEL 7.2, not sure why that might matter, but I thought I'd give you all that I could.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I'm afraid to do that, as I can only SSH into this machine (it's in AWS).  If I bork something, no way to get to recovery...

Comment: I suspect there's some systemd feature at play that I'm not aware of here, but just to check: is `/tmp` a symlink (and if so to what)? Is the `tmp.mount` unit active (`systemd status tmp.mount`)?

Comment: Hi @Gilles, I removed the mask and restarted the `tmp.mount` service, and now the mapping is working!  I'll check and verify that it persists through a reboot!

Comment: @FoxDeploy did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem. Masking tmp.mount didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using the UUID instead. As in changing the fstab to

`UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxx       /tmp    xfs     defaults,nofail 0  2`

Comment: I tried and put in the correct UUID, but it's still not persisting through a reboot.  Are there any special perms I need to apply to the volume?

Comment: I had quotes around my uuid before, when I removed them this worked!

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue on our AWS RHEL 7.3 server (Dec 2016).

I was also able to reproduce the issue in a non AWS VM (via VMware), but only after *masking* **tmp.mount** in **systemd**.

Here's how to check to ensure **tmp.mount** is now masked via systemd on RHEL 7.

To test it:

```
# systemctl tmp.mount  Unknown operation 'tmp.mount'.

# systemctl unmask tmp.mount  Removed symlink
 /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount.

# systemctl status tmp.mount  ● tmp.mount - /tmp    Loaded: loaded
 (/etc/fstab; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)    Active: inactive
 (dead) since Fri 2016-12-02 18:39:04 PST; 2min 47s ago


# systemctl enable tmp.mount  Created symlink from
 /etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount to 
 /usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount.

# systemctl status tmp.mount  ● tmp.mount - /tmp    Loaded: loaded
 (/etc/fstab; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```